# How to return various connected nodes in the return statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Following are the results that I am trying to get

1. Return results that is highlighted in diagram
2. Places (as owner/housemate) should be of 1 & 2 degree connections(status = 1) with MU ,even I don't want to include MU places as well (as owner/housemate)
3. User can have multiple places
4. Place must have only one owner and may have multiple housemates

Result should be in format

```
place, 
[owner, is 1/2/3 degree connection],
[housemates[housmate1(1/2/3 degree connection),housemate( is 1/2/3 degree connection)]])/
```

**This is what I have till now**

```
MATCH (n),
      (n)-[rels:`connected_to` {status: 1}]- (sp: `StayPal`),
      (sp)-[tenant0:owner_of|house_mate]-(place:`Place`),
      (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]-(c: `StayPal`) 
WHERE (ID(n) = {ID_n}) AND NOT(n) - [:house_mate] - (place)
WITH place,
   c,
   tenant, 
   CASE
   WHEN (n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(c) THEN 's'
   WHEN (n)-[:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]-(c) THEN 'ss'
   ELSE 'sss'
   END AS connection 
WITH 
   place,
   collect([tenant, c, connection]) AS tenants RETURN place,
           [tenant IN tenants WHERE type(tenant[0]) = 'owner_of'   | tenant][0] AS ownerArray,                               
           [tenant IN tenants WHERE type(tenant[0]) = 'house_mate' | tenant] AS houseMatesArray
```

**EDIT 2**
Sample data set

```
CREATE
  (mu:MU {name: 'MU1'}),
  (u1:User {number: 1}), (u2:User {number: 2}), (u3:User {number: 3}), (u4:User {number: 4}), (u5:User {number: 5}), (u6:User {number: 6}), (u7:User {number: 7}), (u8:User {number: 8}), (u9:User {number: 9}),
  (mu)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u1),
  (mu)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u2)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u3),
  (mu)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u8),
  (mu)-[:connected_to]->(u9),
  (u4)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u3),
  (u8)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]->(u5),
  (pA:Place {name: 'A'}), (pB:Place {name: 'B'}), (pC:Place {name: 'C'}), (pD:Place {name: 'D'}), (pE:Place {name: 'E'}),
  (mu)<-[:house_mate]-(pA)-[:owner_of]->(u1),
  (u4)<-[:house_mate]-(pB)-[:owner_of]->(u3),
  (u8)<-[:house_mate]-(pC)-[:owner_of]->(u5),
  (u9)<-[:house_mate]-(pD)
```

Comment: I edited your post for clarity, please check if I got everything right.

Comment: @brian looks good to me thanks, FYI I am using it in rails application

Comment: (1) `connected_to` is not a very good name, as basically every relationship expresses that. If these are users who know each other or are friends, `knows` of `friends_with` would make better names. (2) Just out of curiosity, what does `MU` stand for?

Comment: Btw your figure contains a mix of `owner` and `owner_of` relationships.

Comment: (1) connected_to because we can have multiple status which defines it that user knows other user or not (2) MU is just a user, its start point for Query
(3) its owner_of not owner (Typo), I am fixing data model indeed there are issues  in it related to directions

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas I have added correct data set cypher & image

Comment: I think you forgot to add reference with additional match like this `MATCH (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]->(user:User)` then use user further, also results are not correct for place B owner is 3 & housemate 4

Comment: Yes, did forgot. I just updated the answer - please check.

Comment: Looks good but why place c is showing same housemate two times -that is 8 & size of connection is also missing owner/housemates vs MU

Comment: I fixed the duplicate/missing issue and added the "size of connection"-style metric (for connection degrees 1/2/3). Please check.

Comment: Thanks @GaborSzarnyas I am looking into it

Comment: Hey, did it work for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I didn't check it yet. Sure I will take care of answer once I confirm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n {name: 'MU1'})-[:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]->(sp:User),
      (sp)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place:Place)-[:owner_of|house_mate]->(c:User)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:house_mate]-(place)
MATCH
  (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]->(u:User),
  (u)-[rels:connected_to*1..3 {status: 1}]-(n)
WITH DISTINCT place, type(tenant) AS type, u, size(rels) AS connection 
WITH place, collect({type: type, u: u, connection: connection}) AS tenants
RETURN
   place,
   [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'owner_of'   | [tenant.u, tenant.connection]][0] AS owner,
   [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'house_mate' | [tenant.u, tenant.connection]] AS houseMatesArray
```

This query performs *an additional* `MATCH` so that it can gather the users in `place`->`sp` and `place->c` to a single place (under variable `u`).

It returns:

```
╒════════════╤════════════════════╤══════════════════════╕
│"place"     │"owner"             │"houseMatesArray"     │
╞════════════╪════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│{"name":"B"}│[{"number":"3"},"2"]│[[{"number":"4"},"3"]]│
├────────────┼────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│{"name":"C"}│[{"number":"5"},"2"]│[[{"number":"8"},"1"]]│
└────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you @gabor I am understanding and testing it , will update you

Comment: I am always getting owner not housemate I think (but not sure ) there is issue in match `owner_of|house_mate` returning only one matched result, but it should return all matched results

Comment: Please change the first `WITH` to `RETURN` (i.e. `RETURN place, c, tenant, ...`) and inspect its results. Are those okay?

Comment: No results are not expected. The issue is we are only getting places with c which is connected to n, we are not including c which is not connected to n but are connected to place as housemate or owner

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Is the `connected_to` relationship optional? So would a query like this work?

`MATCH (n), (place:Place) 
WHERE ID(n) = {ID_n}
MATCH (c)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[rels:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]-(c:User)
RETURN n, place, c`

Comment: Apologies for making confusion.. I have edited Question with problem diagram, hope this will help us to solve @gabor

Comment: Thanks for updates, I'll take a detailed look later today (in 4-5 hrs). By the way, the edit has some strange characters, please check it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I learnt a lot from you answer @Gabor